# Reading a button on Excel using PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm working with the site which is required to read the excel file cell data using PHP. And I'm successfully made it using the PHP EXCEL. As the progress moved, My client require me to read the button on the excel file which is an excel macro button. So he can able to trigger it, using the site,  without signing in to the server.

Is this possible? Is there anyone can give me an idea regarding this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form data (such as buttons) and macros are not supported by PHPExcel.
To access buttons and execute macros, you'd need a solution based on MS Excel itself (I don't believe Open/Libre Office supports MS Excel macros or VBA Script) which limits you to COM and a Windows platform